# Looking for a statistics textbook

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to deepen my knowledge on statistics, specifically, and probability theory in general. I want to know what textbook could be recommended for someone at my current state of knowledge looking to go deeper. Of course, for this question to make sense I should describe what my current state of knowledge is.

I have a basic but solid understanding of *some* of the core topics of descriptive and inferential statistics; mainly

- The normal and binomial distributions
- Estimation
- Hypothesis testing, $p$-values
- Linear regression
- Correlation coefficients
- Bayes theorem

However, I know my knowledge is far from complete. I ignore the mathematics of distributions such as the $\chi^2$ and $F$, I have zero knowledge on logarithmic regression, I have only a superficial idea of what ANOVA is...

Hopefully this provides a notion of where my knowledge and level of studies are at the moment. What should I read to go deeper?

Answer (score 4):

It depends to some extent on what you mean by a "solid understanding". I will make some suggestions.

**Less mathematical (mostly avoiding measure theory):**

- *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger. This is a standard late undergraduate to early graduate textbook.
- *A Course in Mathematical Statistics* by George Roussas. Another text covering basic probability, point estimation, hypothesis testing, linear models, ANOVA, and so on. (He also has two probability and statistics books more basic than this, and a measure-theoretic probability textbook as well.)

**More mathematical:**

- *Mathmatical Statistics* by Shao. Heavy use of measure theory. There is an accompanying Exercises and Solutions book.
- *Theoretical Statistics: Topics for a Core Course* by Keener. This *might* be the most modern book here. It's the newest one, at least (published in 2010).
- *Theory of Statistics* by Schervish. Possibly the most mathematically sophisticated book here. More Bayesian than the others, I think.

Comment: I loved that you differentiated between more and less mathematical textbooks. I am looking for ones more focused on mathematics, I will definitely look up the ones you mentioned. Thank you!